# Proof of Variance of the Irreducible Error

Tags: machine-learning, variance

In [Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://books.google.com/books?id=qcI_AAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA19#v=onepage&q&f=false), given the general form of a quantitative response between a set of predictor variables and a target variable

$$Y=f(X)+\epsilon$$

and the general form for a prediction over the same predictors and target

$$\hat{Y}=\hat{f}(X)$$

the authors draw what is referred to as a simple conclusion with regard to the expected value of the squared difference between the predicted and actual value of $Y$ and the variance associated with the error term, $\epsilon$, that is, given an estimate $\hat{f}$ and a set of predictors $X$,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[(Y-\hat Y)^2\right]
  &=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)^2\right] \\
  &=\left[f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right]^2 + \text{Var}(\epsilon)
\end{align*}

I am having trouble completing this proof and am hoping for some assistance filling in the blanks.

My work thus far: 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[(Y-\hat Y)^2\right]
  &=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)^2\right] \\
  &=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)
                    \left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)\right] \\
  &=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)
                    \left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)
                   +\epsilon
                    \left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)\right] \\
  &=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)^2
                    +\epsilon
                     \left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)
                   +\epsilon
                    \left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)
                   +\epsilon^2\right] \\
\text{Because the expectation is linear}&\\
  &=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)^2\right]
   +\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon^2+
                   2\epsilon
                     \left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)\right] \\
\text{Because $f$ and $\hat{f}$ are constant}&\\
  &=\left[f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right]^2
   +\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon^2+
                   2\epsilon
                     \left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)\right] \\
\end{align*}

And this is as far as I get. According to the final result

$$\text{Var}(\epsilon)=\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon^2+
                   2\epsilon
                     \left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)\right]$$

but I can not see how to make this work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof can be greatly simplified if we consider that for a random variable $W$ and a constant $c$, $$\operatorname{E}[(W+c)^2] = \operatorname{E}[W^2 + 2cW + c^2] = \operatorname{E}[W^2] + 2c \operatorname{E}[W] + c^2.$$  Consequently, if $\operatorname{E}[W] = 0$, then $$\operatorname{E}[W^2] = \operatorname{Var}[W],$$ hence $$\operatorname{E}[(W+c)^2] = \operatorname{Var}[W] + c^2.$$  Then with the choice $W = \epsilon$, $c = f(X) - \hat f(X)$, the result follows.

---

Alternatively, we can consider the transformed variable $U = W + c$, which clearly satisfies $$\operatorname{Var}[U] = \operatorname{Var}[W].$$  Thus $$\operatorname{E}[U^2] = \operatorname{Var}[U] + \operatorname{E}[U]^2 = \operatorname{Var}[W] + (\operatorname{E}[W] + c)^2,$$ and again, if $\operatorname{E}[W] = 0$, we obtain the identity $$\operatorname{E}[(W+c)^2] = \operatorname{Var}[W] + c^2.$$

Answer (score 3):

Asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191113/proof-for-irreducible-error-statement-in-islr-page-19). Not answered but comments point at two facts that lead me to the following solution.

In comments:

1. Because the mean of $\epsilon$ is zero
2. Because the variance of $\epsilon$ is $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon^2)$

Completed Proof:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[(Y-\hat Y)^2\right]
  &=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)^2\right] \\
  &=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)
                    \left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)\right] \\
  &=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)
                    \left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)
                   +\epsilon
                    \left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)\right] \\
  &=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)^2
                    +\epsilon
                     \left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)
                   +\epsilon
                    \left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)
                   +\epsilon^2\right] \\
\text{Because the expectation is linear}&\\
  &=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)^2\right]
   +\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon^2\right]
   +2\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon
                     \left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)\right] \\
\text{Because $f$ and $\hat{f}$ are constant}&\\
  &=\left[f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right]^2
   +\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon^2\right]
   +2\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon
                     \left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)\right] \\
\text{Because the mean of $\epsilon$ is zero}&\\
  &=\left[f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right]^2
   +\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon^2\right] \\
\text{Because the variance of $\epsilon$ is $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon^2)$}&\\
  &=\left[f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right]^2 + \text{Var}(\epsilon)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

This is merely a clarification of the proof by heropup:

*Proposition*: $E(Y - \hat{Y})^2 = [f(X) - \hat f(X)]^2 + Var(\epsilon)$

*Proof*:

By definition of $\epsilon$, its mean is $0$, so:

$E(\epsilon) = 0$ ...1

Let c be some constant (specifically, $\epsilon$ is independent of c )

Then,

$(\epsilon + c)^2 = \epsilon^2 + 2.c.\epsilon + c^2$

Computing expected value:

$E[(\epsilon + c)^2] = E[\epsilon ^ 2 + 2.c. \epsilon + c^2]$

$E[(\epsilon + c)^2] = E[\epsilon ^ 2] + E[2.c. \epsilon] + E[c^2]$

$E[(\epsilon + c)^2] = E[\epsilon ^ 2] + 2.c.E[\epsilon] + E[c^2]$ ...2

Now, Variance of a random variable t, with mean $\mu$, is defined as:

$Var(t) = E[(t - \mu)^2]$

If the mean is $0$, this becomes:

$Var(t) = E[t^2]$

Taking $t = \epsilon$, for which the mean is $0$ (from (1)), we get:

$Var(\epsilon) = E[\epsilon^2]$ ...3

Substituting for $E[\epsilon^2]$ from (3) in (2), and since $E[\epsilon] = 0$ from (1), we get:

$E[(\epsilon + c)^2] = Var(\epsilon) + E[c^2]$

Now, taking $c = f(X) - \hat f(X)$ (since $\epsilon$ is given to be independent of $X$), we get:

$E[(\epsilon + f(X) - \hat f(X))^2] = Var(\epsilon) + E[(f(X) - \hat f(X))^2]$ ...4

But we also know that $Y=f(X)+\epsilon$ and $\hat Y = \hat f(X)$. So, substituting these into 4, we get:

$E[(Y - \hat Y)^2] = E[(f(X) - \hat f(X))^2] + Var(\epsilon)$ $\square$